# Battery icon not showing AND keyboard stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, battery

My battery icon is not showing, and my laptop keyboard has stopped working after I updated. The boot takes longer than normal as well.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and my upower -d output is:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice


power supply:         no
updated:              Thu 02 Jan 2020 10:10:20 AM EST (1002 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
unknown
warning-level:       none
icon-name:          'battery-missing-symbolic'

 Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.7
on-battery:      no
lid-is-closed:   no
lid-is-present:  yes
critical-action: HybridSleep
```

I am using:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
AMD® A9-9420 radeon r5, 5 compute cores 2c+3g × 2 
3.28.2
64-bit
```

Here is the full lscpu output:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          21
Model:               112
Model name:          AMD A9-9420 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G
Stepping:            0
CPU MHz:             2403.504
CPU max MHz:         3000.0000
CPU min MHz:         1400.0000
BogoMIPS:            5989.06
Virtualization:      AMD-V
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           64K
L2 cache:            1024K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0,1
```

Also, my keyboard does not seem to appear when I run hwinfo --short.

```
cpu:                                                            
                       AMD A9-9420 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G, 2500 MHz
                       AMD A9-9420 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G, 2714 
MHz
mouse:
  /dev/input/mice      Dell Optical Wheel Mouse
  /dev/input/mice      Elan Touchpad
monitor:
                       N156BGA-EA2 LCD Monitor
graphics card:
                       ATI VGA compatible controller
sound:
                       ATI Audio device
                       AMD Audio device
storage:
                       AMD FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
network:
  enp2s0               Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit 
Ethernet controller
  wlp1s0               Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless 
Network Adapter
network interface:
  wlp1s0               Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  enp2s0               Ethernet network interface
disk:
  /dev/sda             HP SSD S700 120G
partition:
  /dev/sda1            Partition
  /dev/sda2            Partition
cdrom:
  /dev/sr0             HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GUE0N
usb controller:
                       AMD FCH USB XHCI Controller
                       AMD FCH USB EHCI Controller
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       AMD Host bridge
                       AMD Host bridge
                       AMD PCI bridge
                       AMD FCH LPC Bridge
                       AMD Host bridge
                       AMD Host bridge
                       AMD Host bridge
                       AMD Host bridge
                       AMD PCI bridge
                       AMD Host bridge
                       AMD Host bridge
                       AMD Host bridge
                       AMD Host bridge
hub:
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Advanced Micro Devices Hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
bluetooth:
                       Qualcomm Atheros Bluetooth Device
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
                       AMD Encryption controller
                       AMD IOMMU
                       AMD FCH SMBus Controller
                       Syntek EasyCamera
```

Are these somehow connected? Any ideas on how I can either get my battery icon back or my keyboard working again?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you add information on the hardware you are using?

Comment: Sure thing. What should I add?

Comment: That already looks pretty complete. Perhaps you could also add the laptop model; maybe someone will recognize problematic hardware support.